# Correctly creating multiple instances of lightbox for website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am seeking to use a jQuery / JS lightbox I found across a 1 page website, I'd like to use it 7 times to hold 7 unique sets of content but I am failing to implement it correctly for the other 6 instances.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lightBox = $('#lightbox'),
    lightBoxContent = $('#lb-content');

var positionLightbox = function() {
    var veiwWidth = $(window).width(),
        lbContentMargin = (veiwWidth / 2) - 400,
        lbContent = $('#lb-content');

    lbContent.css({
        'left' : lbContentMargin,
        'top' : $(window).scrollTop() - 150 + 'px'
    });
};

$('#search-submit').click(function() {
    lightBox.fadeIn(function() {
        lightBoxContent.show();                               
    });
    positionLightbox();
});

$('#lb-close').click(function() {
    lightBox.hide();
    lightBoxContent.hide();
    });
});
```

**Mark-Up:**

```
<!-- light box -->

                <div id="lightbox"></div>
                <div id="lb-content">
                <span id="lb-close">x</span>
                <h1>More content here.</h1><br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec commodo justo. Suspendisse vel facilisis enim. Nulla lorem ante, auctor et malesuada ac, porttitor in lectus. Fusce congue pharetra tincidunt. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam dapibus nec neque ut accumsan.</p>   

                </div>

<!-- // light box -->
```

Duplicating the code in 6 new instances didn't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lightBox = $('#lightbox2'),
    lightBoxContent = $('#lb-content2');

var positionLightbox = function() {
    var veiwWidth = $(window).width(),
        lbContentMargin = (veiwWidth / 2) - 400 + 'px',
        lbContent = $('#lb-content2');

    lbContent.css({
        'left' : lbContentMargin,
        'top' : $(window).scrollTop() - 350 + 'px'
    });
};

$('#search-submit2').click(function() {
    lightBox.fadeIn(function() {
        lightBoxContent.show();                               
    });
    positionLightbox();
});

$('#lb-close2').click(function() {
    lightBox.hide();
    lightBoxContent.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where are the other six instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure where the other content is or supposed to be but, assuming your lightbox code is correct and your html too (for what you need it to do) then you dont need to repeat the jquery code 7xs. Keep the same code and ............. lets assume that you have this html as your content

```
<div id="lightbox"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox2"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox3"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox4"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox5"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox6"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
<div id="lightbox7"> content here to be lightboxed </div>
```

then in your jQuery, you put all these id selectors in your code as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lightBox = $('#lightbox, #lightbox2,#lightbox3,#lightbox4,#lightbox5,#lightbox6,#lightbox7'),
    lightBoxContent = $('/* same here for the 7 lb-content 1 through 7 */ ');

etc
```

Essentially, group all your selectors to reuse the same code.